# Minor Display Bug for Many Badges

Tags: bug, design

It looks like there's a small display overlap issue when a user has many badges.

It's a rare edge case, and you can guess who exposes it :)

[image]

For reference this is in Chrome (Version 43.0.2357.130 m) on Windows 8.1