# User profile badge text wrapping issue

Tags: bug, design

I was browsing a question which was answered by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) when I noticed this:

[image: bug screenshot]

The container which consists of the reputation and badges appears to not be large enough to fit everything in there. It also appears consistent amongst the high-rep/high-badge users: [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell), for instance:

[image]

This issue could be related to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284176/profile-display-gets-cut-off-for-users-with-lots-of-badges) (and [others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297850/minor-display-bug-for-many-badges)), although in this case it is wrapped rather than being cut off. Is this the intended behavior? It seems as though having it wrap this way makes it a bit more difficult to associate what numbers go with what statistic.

At different magnification percentages everything will fit in a single line just fine, but at the default 100% magnification for me it was an issue.

I've been able to reproduce this issue in both Firefox (42.0-2) on Arch and Chrome on OS X.

Comment: When you get so much text you will either have to wrap the text or make it smaller (and harder to read), either way you go you will find someone who doesn't like it.

Comment: @JoeW fair. Although the solution that was apparently implemented was increasing the width, which I guess was in addition to adding the wrapping.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of having to widen the user cards to keep everything on one line every time this occurs due to the counts growing or even any unrelated layout changes, I suggest just letting the badge counts wrap, and instead adding `display: inline-block` to each badge count so at the very least the number doesn't get separated from the icon when wrapping:

```css
.-flair > span:not(.reputation-score) {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug and *not* by design. Thank you for bringing it to our attention. Unfortunately **Jon Skeet** and **Marc Gravell** are the extreme rare cases when it comes to large rep and badge totals. When we updated some items in the user cards recently, we didn't check this high edge case.

This has been fixed as you can see in [this sample Jon Skeet answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479).

[image: Fixed Jon Skeet User Card]

Comment: Great, thanks for clarification (for real this time!) That said, I'm still seeing the issue even after clearing my cache and restarting Firefox. Is the update not in production yet? (I'm testing at 100%/default magnification fwiw)

Comment: @ChrisSprague I believe it is in production. I've tested this in Chrome, Firefox, and IE and it looks as I pictured it above. It could be a CDN issue though. Give it some time. If you're still seeing the issue, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: And now we wait until each of these users has 1K gold badges for this to happen again.  But that's a ways out, at least. :)

Comment: It looks to me like it [has not been fixed](http://i.imgur.com/YPYi5Tn.png)

Comment: @TravisJ Likewise, I'm still seeing the issue.

Comment: Still broken, unfortunately :(

Comment: still broken for me

Comment: Yeah, this is back. :( It's noticeable both here on the post you link to and on other network sites (like [meta.se]).

Comment: @Hynes still being reported at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319790/badge-overflow-in-profiles

Comment: Not fixed (Firefox on Ubuntu) : http://i.stack.imgur.com/mxSHg.png

Comment: Still not fixed on Chrome in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: As of June-12-2016, the profile / badges / reputation line wrapping is not fixed (win 7 x64 chrome and ie / win 10 x64 chrome / edge / ie).

Comment: @Hynes As of Nov. 17, 2016 it's still wrapping on Chrome (Windows 7 x64).

Comment: Just joined the "badge counts wrapping into the next line" club with my 100th gold badge.</humblebrag>

Comment: This is still an issue https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376838/should-we-tidy-user-data-display-especially-for-high-rep-users