# High-rep user cards wrapping again

Tags: bug, design, user-card

It seems the bug reported in [User profile badge text wrapping issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312042/41071) is happening again (or still?). This is what I see at default magnification in FF 43 on Win 10:

[image: Eric Lippert user card with wrapping]

[image: Jon Skeet user card with wrapping]

[image: Jon Skeet user card with wrapping, 2019]

Based on the above linked question, I assume this is (still) not intentional. There are also several users in the comments there reporting that this was never fixed.

Comment: Happening on OSX as well while using chrome.

Comment: Wouldn't even be so bad if the number and icon wrapped together.

Comment: Just reset their badges count and problem solved ;-) They would get new ones soon enough.

Comment: When are they going to introduce a minimum width instead of a fixed width and use `white-space: nowrap`? Are we seriously going to have a question every time Jon Skeet gets another digit?

Comment: not been a problem for my rep :-(

Comment: Do you think that there are a batch of unit/functional/integration tests at StackExchange HQ in a folder labelled Skeet tests that test things like this? If a developer breaks a Skeet test, then Jon Skeet gets another badge.

Comment: Could this be a side effect of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272563/134584 ?

Comment: Also the circles from the badges are cut off on the right side if you post an answer/question.

Comment: Also on Linux Kubntu 14.04 chrome

Comment: @shoover, I think they broke it before/with Winterbash. Alot of css got messed up around that time :p

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome 47

Comment: @JamesENL That comment sounds like a feature request and should probably be another meta question. :-P

Comment: Still an unsolved issue over 3 years later, yet they can do unicorns for April Fools no problem. Priorities are not there.