# Badge Overflow in profiles

Tags: bug

As can be seen in this image:

[image]

profiles of users with lots of badges are overflowing into another line. See in action in this question: [Java exception not caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375113/java-exception-not-caught)

I am using Chrome latest with Windows 7. In case this is an unexpected bug, please fix it. Thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312042/user-profile-badge-text-wrapping-issue/312187)'s a duplicate bug, which is marked as fixed.

Comment: SO search is not so good. I am closing this question.

Comment: -1. It is a square not a free-hand circle. Where am I supposed to look?

Comment: @resueman:  I wouldn't call this a duplicate because *the bug is back*.  Since the other question marks it as "complete", closing this as a dupe is misleading at best.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate issue, have pinged the dev in a comment to their answer (as well as others have since it was supposed to be fixed) and have removed the status tag on the dupe - hopefully it'll get some attention.