# Jon Skeet's badges have broken the CSS again

Tags: bug, design

A picture says a thousand words:

[image: Jon Skeet]

It is [not the first time Jon Skeet broke the CSS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307439/jon-skeet-has-too-many-badges). I see two solutions:

- We can adjust the size of the profile box, so we have no line break. There is more than enough space for this.
- If we can live with the line break, we could use a `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) between the badge and the number.

Comment: IMO, once you reach a thousand of any medal, should just switch to K.

Comment: @Compass feature request?

Comment: Sometimes I feel like some people are just looking at Jon's profile 24/7 to spot these things...

Comment: if you develop in `C#` and `LINQ`, every second answer is from Jon ;) @JustDoIt

Comment: Or, we could just ignore when Jon Skeet breaks the CSS... Seriously, more hours have been spent worrying about Skeet's badges than have been spent closing bad questions </hyperbole>.

Comment: We don't want [broken windows](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-broken-window-theory/).

Comment: Didn't you know? The CSS is already fixed. Jon Skeet just hasn't allowed it to take effect yet. Once he does, there won't even need to be a new build with the fix.

Comment: These high-rep users think they can get away with everything.

Comment: I think, as a workaround, he should get an extra 'platinum' badge for this that ensures his css stays broken forever.

Comment: @NickDewitt Have a 1mil rep badge?

Comment: @pydsigner ooh yeah, then surely once that was achieved it would be a race to the first rockstar programmer to go 'platinum 7 times'.. how will the css ever cope, Jon only knows. ;-)

Comment: @JustDoIt I think it's more so that his answers are everywhere so they get immediately noticed

Comment: Actually, that picture only has 4 words

Comment: @JustDoIt - there probably *are* people looking at Jon's profile 24 hours a day, seven days a week, 365 days a year. Imagine the pressure this guy must be under..! :-)

Comment: Just set the `min-width` @ `1sk`.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. He broke in a new way.

Comment: Reset stats....

Comment: Has been asked many many times, [Badge Overflow in profiles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319790) [User profile badge text wrapping issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312042)

Answer (score 22):

As already [suggested in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307446/88204), truncate the silver/bronze counts to "thousands", similar to rep. As [Tas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4143855/tas) suggested, use one decimal place.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes, I wonder why we even keep track anymore...

Comment: What happens when Jon Skeet starts getting into the hundred thousands?

Comment: @PyRulez Switch to 0.1m, natch.

Comment: @KyleHale Okay, what about when he gets above our number words?

Comment: There's a huge difference between having 1900 bronze badges and 1000 bronze badges. Should this display 1.9k in this case, or simply 1k?

Comment: This was already provided both [in the comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320539/jon-skeets-badges-have-broken-the-css-again#comment330717_320539) and in [the linked dupe](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307446/3001626). If there anything I hate about SO is this tendency for a shameless plagiarism by way too many users around here.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. This was already suggested. Didn't see it before I answered. I added a link. Just a friendly reminder to you to be cognizant of your tone when commenting.

Comment: @PyRulez I put no limits on Jon Skeet's ability, but the man is mortal. Pretty sure he's never making it to 7 digits without manual intervention.

Comment: What's the point posting the same answer in the dupe? If this was already provided on another thread, this should be just closed as a dupe and your answer adds nothing new. If the issue is different, then the answer should be different too. Also, are you claiming that you haven't seen the first comment in this thread (which was posted a day before your answer) neither?

Comment: @David The same was mentioned [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284242/4099593) way before the answer which you pointed out as the original copy of this answer. But as this is MSO, copying answers is not a problem. (Though I agree that there's no point in having same answers in everyplace)

Comment: @BhargavRao The answer I'm pointing out is linked in the question by the OP himself. I don't accept this excuse of "*Oh it's not my fault I haven't read the question so my answer is valid*".

Comment: This is still an issue. Either do the `0.0k` fix or group the badge icon to be grouped with the number and allow it to gracefully linebreak. It know it could take business 1 month to decide but its a 1 minute CSS fix. Common.. my OCD is killing me!